# Check if the rabbitMQ message is successfully routed or not

Tags: scala, akka

I'm using `akka-stream-alpakka-amqp` to publish messages to `rabbitmq exchange`, I want to know if there a way to determine if the `message` is properly routed to the queue with `akka-streams` currently in reponse I get http status `200` regardless the message is routed or not

sample message creation

```
val headers = new java.util.HashMap[String, AnyRef]()
headers.put("hash-on", hashOn)
headers.put("message-type", messageType)
val basicProps = new BasicProperties().builder().headers(headers).build()

OutgoingMessage(
  bytes = ByteString(body),
  immediate = false,
  mandatory = false)
  .withProperties(basicProps)


Source.single(outgoingMessage).runWith(sink)
```

Comment: Can't you just look into the RabbitMQ management interface? Or use dead lettering; https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html which will publish rejected messages o another exchange.

Comment: @Johansson I can't use the mgmt interface for this, need to done it via code depend on the `status (routed or not)` I should execute some additional logic, also due to some limitation I'm not allowed to listen to another queue any way it's good that you mentioned because I wasn't aware of it since I'm new to RabbitMQ as well

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [Publisher Confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#publisher-confirms) feature.

You'll have to set `confirm.select` on the channel, and then send a message as `mandatory`.

Then you'll get `basic.ack` or `basic.nack` response for every message send to broker, and before that you'll receive `basic.return` info with information whether message was routed or not.